# Firefox CSS outline bug?

Tags: css, firefox, outline

On Chrome and IE9 the CSS outline that I'm specifying does exactly what I want, and acts as a second border around the element I'm styling.

On Firefox though, the outline gets expanded outwards so that it encompasses the ::after pseudo element that I've generated, as well as the main element.

Is this a bug, or expected?  Any good/easy/clean workarounds for it?  I'd prefer to avoid adding extra markup if possible.

Comment: Post your code....

Comment: Normalize.css makes browsers render all elements more consistently and in line with modern standards. It precisely targets only the styles that need normalizing. - http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: Not my own code, but here's an example.  http://codepen.io/romainberger/pen/nuxlh  

Switching from outline to box-shadow works, but I'm still curious if outline can be correctly used somehow.  Is there an obscure property that I'm missing, that sort of thing.

Comment: Adding normalize.css makes no difference Luis.

Comment: If this is the bug I think it is, it should have been fixed a few months ago. Are you testing on an older version of Firefox?

Comment: 35.0, installed today.

Comment: Hello, this is not fixed yet?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yeah it looks like a bug(sorta) in firefox, check it out **[here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=687311)**. Now some people seem to argue if this is to be expected if children are absolute or not, or rather if the outline should cover 'everything', which is kinda weird, and not at all the expected behavior, when using `position: absolute`, at least for me.

**Solution 1:**

- work you way with a extra pseudo selector, for the `.main` class(I see you're not using the `:before` class so you can go with that), and work your way from there, seems to work fine all across the board.
- check out the **[demo here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ByRNVp)** or the snippet bellow

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border: 2px solid #f00;
}
.main:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid #00f;
  /*adjust if needed if using border-box*/
  top: -4px;
  right: -4px;
  bottom: -4px;
  left: -4px;
  z-index: -1;
}
.main:after {
  content: 'Hello';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: -50px;
}
.wtf {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 90px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="main"></div>
<div class="wtf">
  <p>In Chrome and Safari the 'Hello' is outside of the outline.</p>
  <p>In firefox the outline is extended and the 'Hello' is inside the outline. Bug from Firefox or is there a way to fix this?</p>
</div>
```

**Solution 2:**

- use box-shadow prop. to achieve that effect without extra :pseudo selectors
- check out the **[demo here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEmPvY)** or the snippet bellow

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border: 2px solid #f00;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #00f;
}
.main:after {
  content: 'Hello';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: -50px;
}
.wtf {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 90px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="main"></div>
<div class="wtf">
  <p>In Chrome and Safari the 'Hello' is outside of the outline.</p>
  <p>In firefox the outline is extended and the 'Hello' is inside the outline. Bug from Firefox or is there a way to fix this?</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, this looks good solution. But if main's border width changed, :after  's border or box-shadow position is changed. How can we solve this? thanks