# before pseudoelement appearing different on chrome and firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

So I'm experiencing this weird bug where Chrome doesn't display the pseudoelement inside my div with class "to_top", it works perfectly on Chrome but Firefox doesn't display the horizontal line outside the square, instead it appears inside and enlarges the container div instead, this is just sad. Any way to fix this?

Here is my code (sorry for inline styling but taht's not the problem here):

```css
.to_top::before{content:""; position:absolute; width:100%; height:1px;  border-top:1px solid red; left:0px; top:-5px;}
```

```html
<div style="width:100%; height:auto; display:flex; flex-direction:column;">
    <div style="width:100%; height:300px; display:flex; flex-direction:column; position:relative; align-items:center; background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(36, 31, 28, 1.0), rgba(36, 31, 28, 0.9)); justify-content:center;">
     <div class="to_top" style="width:50px; height:55px; outline:1px solid red; display:flex; position:absolute; right:50px; top:50px; overflow:visible;">
      <!--<span style="width:50px; height:1px; border-top:1px solid red; position:absolute; left:0px;  top:-5px;"></span>-->
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-up" style="font-size:30px; color:red; margin:auto;"></i>
  </div>
  <div style="width:auto; height:auto; display:flex; margin:15px 0px;">
      <a href="" style="width:50px; height:50px; border-radius:50%; background-color:#5D973A; display:flex; margin:0px 15px;"><i class="fa fa-tripadvisor" style="margin:auto; font-size:22px; color:#292421;"></i></a>
      <a href="" style="width:50px; height:50px; border-radius:50%; background-color:#5D973A; display:flex; margin:0px 15px;"><i class="fa fa-yelp" style="margin:auto; font-size:22px; color:#292421;"></i></a>
   <a href="" style="width:50px; height:50px; border-radius:50%; background-color:#5D973A; display:flex; margin:0px 15px;"><i class="fa fa-facebook" style="margin:auto; font-size:22px; color:#292421;"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div style="width:auto; height:auto; display:flex; margin:15px 0px;">
      <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-transform:uppercase; margin:0px 12px; color:rgba(255,255,255,0.9); font-weight:500;">MENU</a>
   <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-transform:uppercase; margin:0px 12px; color:rgba(255,255,255,0.9); font-weight:500;">LOCALIZACIÓN</a>
   <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-transform:uppercase; margin:0px 12px; color:rgba(255,255,255,0.9); font-weight:500;">HORARIO</a>
   <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-transform:uppercase; margin:0px 12px; color:rgba(255,255,255,0.9); font-weight:500;">CONTACTO</a>
   <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-transform:uppercase; margin:0px 12px; color:rgba(255,255,255,0.9); font-weight:500;">OPINIONES</a>
  </div>
 </div>
    <div style="width:100%; height:125px; display:flex; flex-direction:column; background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(91, 150, 56, 1.0), rgba(91, 150, 56, 0.9)); justify-content:center; align-items:center;">
     <span style="font-size:16px; color:rgba(255,255,255,0.9); margin:10px 0px; text-transform:upercase;">COMIDA TRADICIONAL HECHA CON <i class="fa fa-heart" style="font-size:15px; color:rgba(255,255,255,0.9); margin:0px 3px;"></i> EN MÁLAGA</span>
  <div style="display:flex; width:auto; height:20px; margin:10px 0px; align-items:center;">
      <span style="font-size:13px; color:rgba(255,255,255,0.9); text-transform:uppercase;">Copyright © 2018 Nombre del Restaurante</span>
   <span style="width:1px; height:20px; border-right:2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.9); margin:0px 10px;"></span>
   <span style="font-size:13px; color:rgba(255,255,255,0.9); text-transform:uppercase;">DISEÑO WEB POR GGB</span>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well since you are using `top: -5px`, how did you determine that it wasn’t Firefox actually doing things wrong here to begin with …? And what is it that you are actually trying to achieve here? At least with this example I can’t see why you might be trying to use a pseudo element to achieve what simply making the element’s top border one pixel thicker could achieve as well.

Comment: (`1px solid red` is not a height, btw.)

Comment: It's not possible to do with borders, what I want is to have that little line a bit over the square container, kind of like a "hat" if you get me

Comment: @CBroe true, I fixed it but still not working

Comment: Looks like it is the combination of `display: flex` and `position: absolute`, that makes Firefox handle things wrong(?) here. Guess adding an additional container element could perhaps fix this.

Comment: I tried using a span element instead of a pseudo element and still looks wrong, removed flex too...

Comment: I was talking about the properties of the element itself, not the pseudo element. Try and toggle flex in dev tools, then you’ll see what effect it has in Firefox. Chrome doesn’t care either way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firefox CSS outline bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28009963/firefox-css-outline-bug)

Answer (score 0):

Use border instead of outline for the sqare.